# Multi-Dimensional Time Series Forecasting - using model predictions as future input

Tags: time-series, forecasting, conv-neural-network

I'm building a CNN that uses 10 different time series (all updated at the same time steps) to predict the value of another, 11th time series.

What makes this problem a bit different from the typical time series forecasting problem is that for all the time steps I'm trying to forecast into, I actually have reasonable estimates of the inputs (the 10 time series). In this problem the estimation of the inputs is treated as a black box, but can be taken as highly reliable estimates.

So, is there a benefit to using my model's prediction at one time step as input for predicting the next?

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to get features of both CNNs and RNNs. RNNs do what you're describing, inherently.

Comment: Just as long as you take into account the uncertainty in the predictions of your predictors.